# Finitely generated torsion-free group which is not geometrically finite?

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, group-cohomology, geometric-group-theory

I know (using group cohomology, for example) that if a group $G$ admits a finite dimensional $K(G,1)$ complex, then $G$ needs to be torsion-free.

I'm interested in the converse of the statement.

**Q:** If a group $G$ is finitely generated torsion-free, then is it necessary that $G$ is geometrically finite (i.e. $G$ admits a finite dimensional $K(G,1)$ complex)
(We need finitely generated $G$ otherwise we have examples like $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{Z}$)

I don't feel like it is true, but I can't come up with an example of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "geometrically finite?"

Comment: @MoisheKohan added definition.

Comment: One can verify that all groups given in answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708432/finitely-generated-torsion-free-group-which-is-not-geometrically-finite?noredirect=1#comment9969270_4708432) question are torsion-free. Since they are also finitely generated and not finitely-presented, they provide many examples. If you want more examples (say finitely presentable but not geometrically finite), let me know.

Comment: See also Holt's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788307/examples-of-non-finitely-presented-groups?rq=1).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think my formulation was not good. I would like K(G,1) to be finite dimensional, not a finite complex. I'll update the question, sorry for changing the question.

Comment: At some point you have to stop modifying your question, otherwise it is impossible to answer. Is this the last version?

Comment: @MoisheKohan you're right, my apologies. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: There are many finitely generated groups, including torsion-free ones, that are not finitely presentable (and hence not $\pi_1$ of any finite complex). An example of finite cohomological dimension is the semidirect product $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]^2\rtimes\mathbf{Z}$, where $p$ is any fixed prime and the action is given by powers of the diagonal matrix $(p,1/p)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Thompson's group F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups) is an example of a torsion-free group of type $F_\infty$ (which is stronger than finite presentability and means existence of a classifying space with finitely many cells in each dimension). To see that Thompson's group F is torsion-free, note that it is realized as a subgroup of the (orientation-preserving) homeomorphism group of $[0,1]$. At the same time, this group has infinite cohomological dimension since it contains free abelian groups of arbitrarily high rank.